# Understanding CAST/REPLACE Query in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited some SQL queries to update and work on from a Node project. I am getting an error with a part of my SQL query in my SQL Server database. But before I address the error I'd like to better understand what one part of my query is actually doing (I work in Node and JavaScript regularly but am still learning SQL).

This is the part of the SQL Server query in question:

```
AND CAST(REPLACE(LEFT( RM20101.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', RM20101.DOCNUMBR)), '-', '') AS INT) = 481492) a
WHERE a.DocumentAmount != 0
```

What is happening with the above code? Is it looking for the value for `RM20101.DOCNUMBR` and then transforming it so as to replace a `-` with an empty string, and then casting it as an INT? And is it assigning that value to a variable, `a`?

Comment: Given `'12345-67890'`, it takes `'12345'` and casts it to an int. The quoted portion is invalid on its own, I assume you have `select (select ... from ... where something AND cast() = 481492) a where a.DocumentAmount != 0`.

Comment: No. It's not assigning that value to `a`. Is that on a `JOIN` statement? It is comparing the transformed value = 481492. The `JOIN` is aliased as `a`. `a.DocumentAmount` is most likely a column in the joined table. If you show the whole query, we would better understand, rather than guessing.

Comment: In *most* languages it's a safe bet that parentheses (`()`) will be matched. Since you have more closing parentheses than opening ones, it's a reasonable assumption that some parts of the above code aren't *related* to the `CAST(REPLACE(...` bits.

Comment: I have added the larger context of the code above.

Comment: @Ademo it is still an invalid portion on its own. Either add more, up to the inner `select`, or, if you don't have an inner `select`, it's invalid in principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is firstly finding CHAR Index from Doc number left of the '-' delimiter, then it takes left part of that portion and replace '-' delimiter if there with blank and then it compares with values 481492.

`Cast` is doing Conversion from `varchar` to `Int` data type.
`Replace` is replacing delimeter.